# How to get data on click using 2 links with 2 different url addys

Tags: jquery

This is working for me to get data from another page on my site and append to newDiv

```
    $.get('www.mysite.com', function (data) {
      $(data).find('#DIV1').appendTo('#NEWDIV');
    });

    <div id="NEWDIV"></div>
```

But i'd like to set up 2 links and get the data on click , i've read some tuts , but very confused on how to get this working. I'd like to set up 2 links , and click them and append either data to the newDiv , while removing the current data. I assume i will need 2 get functions as the data for each link is coming from another page.

```
<div class="getdatalinks">
  <li class="getdiv1"><a>GET DIV1 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
  <li class="getdiv2"><a>GET DIV2 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="getdatalinks">
  <li class="getdiv1"><a class='getLink' data-div="div1" data-url="site1.com">GET DIV1 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
  <li class="getdiv2"><a class='getLink' data-div="div2" data-url="site2.com">GET DIV2 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
</div>
```

then hook it up:

```
$(function(){
     $("a.getLink").on("click",function(){
         var url=$(this).data("url"), dv="#"+$(this).data("div");
         $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#NEWDIV").find(dv).remove();
            $(data).find(dv).appendTo('#NEWDIV');
         });
    });
});
```

`data-url` will give `url` to get data from and `data-div` will give id of div to find in returned data.

Comment: working good , but its not removing one div# when you click on the 2nd link , both appear , then if reclick 1st link , both appear but in different order - here i have it on working site - http://football23.myfantasyleague.com/2015/options?L=62165&O=247&SEQNO=17

Comment: got it working had to change to this  $("#NEWDIV").find("div").remove();

Answer (score 1):

Can simplify the ajax by using load()

```
<div class="getdatalinks">
  <li class="getdiv1"><a href="url1.php" data-content="#div1">GET DIV1 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
  <li class="getdiv2"><a  href="url1.php" data-content="#div1">GET DIV2 APPEND TO NEWDIV</a></li>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.getdatalinks a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#newDiv').load(this.href +' '+ $(this).data('content') );        
});
```

`load()` allows setting a space delimited selector in the url and will then get that document fragment from the new content